# Youtube API Community Data Username

Tags: python, youtube

I'm working on a python script to scan a youtube video for the usernames of people that have commented on the video and write their usernames to a file.

I'm using the youtube API, and I'm able to get the comment authors when I print the whole response of comment_entry.

Is there a way to isolate the usernames?

For example, entering 9bZkp7q19f0 (Gangnam Style) as the video_id will yield (in the first comment's set of values):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<ns0:entry xmlns:ns0="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:ns1="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007"><ns0:category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind" term="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#comment" /><ns0:id>http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/9bZkp7q19f0/comments/LZQPQhLyRh9VQaVtT18UUKqLpyWBdytJ7B-JRTu0cf8</ns0:id><ns0:author><ns0:name>THAsweatyGamer</ns0:name><ns0:uri>https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/THAsweatyGamer</ns0:uri></ns0:author><ns0:content type="text">sometimes butï»¿ not always</ns0:content><ns0:updated>2013-05-17T12:30:27.000Z</ns0:updated><ns0:published>2013-05-17T12:30:27.000Z</ns0:published><ns0:title type="text">sometimes butï»¿ not ...</ns0:title><ns0:link href="https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/9bZkp7q19f0?client=TJNP_YT_BOT" rel="related" type="application/atom+xml" /><ns0:link href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9bZkp7q19f0" rel="alternate" type="text/html" /><ns0:link href="https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/9bZkp7q19f0/comments/LZQPQhLyRh-b_np-G6TRfbDU8xlXaRcR_qXeRfla_vo?client=TJNP_YT_BOT" rel="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#in-reply-to" type="application/atom+xml" /><ns0:link href="https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/9bZkp7q19f0/comments/LZQPQhLyRh9VQaVtT18UUKqLpyWBdytJ7B-JRTu0cf8?client=TJNP_YT_BOT" rel="self" type="application/atom+xml" /><ns1:videoid>9bZkp7q19f0</ns1:videoid></ns0:entry>
```

I want to isolate **`<ns0:author><ns0:name>THAsweatyGamer</ns0:name><ns0:uri>https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/THAsweatyGamer</ns0:uri></ns0:author>`** to write the user name to a file. Using comment_entry.author yields:

```
[<atom.Author object at 0x02CE5B50>]
[<atom.Author object at 0x02CE5EB0>]
[<atom.Author object at 0x02CED230>]
[<atom.Author object at 0x02CED5B0>]
[<atom.Author object at 0x02CED910>]
[<atom.Author object at 0x02CEDCD0>]
[<atom.Author object at 0x02CF6070>]
[<atom.Author object at 0x02CF63D0>]
[<atom.Author object at 0x02CF6750>]
[<atom.Author object at 0x02CF6B10>]
[<atom.Author object at 0x02CF6E90>]
[<atom.Author object at 0x03591210>]
[<atom.Author object at 0x03591590>]
[<atom.Author object at 0x03591950>]
[<atom.Author object at 0x03591CD0>]
[<atom.Author object at 0x0359B050>]
[<atom.Author object at 0x0359B3D0>]
[<atom.Author object at 0x0359B750>]
[<atom.Author object at 0x0359BAD0>]
[<atom.Author object at 0x0359BE50>]
[<atom.Author object at 0x035A31D0>]
[<atom.Author object at 0x035A3530>]
[<atom.Author object at 0x035A3890>]
[<atom.Author object at 0x035A3BF0>]
```

My script (so far) is:

```
import gdata.youtube
import gdata.youtube.service

yt_service = gdata.youtube.service.YouTubeService()
yt_service.ssl = True
yt_service.developer_key = #mykey
yt_service.client_id = #myclientid
yt_service.source = #myclientid

video_id = raw_input("Enter the video's ID")

comment_feed = yt_service.GetYouTubeVideoCommentFeed(video_id= video_id)
for comment_entry in comment_feed.entry:
  print comment_entry.author
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an XML parser to extract the data you are looking for. Here's a quick example that uses Python's [Element Tree XML API](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('youtube.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

print root[2][0].text
print root[2][1].text
```

This gives you the following output:

`THAsweatyGamer`
`https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/THAsweatyGamer`

Note: `youtube.xml` in the example code above is a file containing the YouTube XML output that you included in your question.